# How to make a repeating background?

Tags: modifiers, game-engine

I am currently working on a space game, and I want there to be stars in the background. I don't want to have to duplicate the stars over and over because that would be a waste of time and have way too many verts. Is it possible to have a background repeat over and over without having too many vertices?

Comment: There are several ways of achieving this, can you elaborate on what you have so far and what tools you're using?

Comment: I'd just use an image texture as an environment background.